# Difference between Browserify transforms + sourcemaps when run via CLI vs programatically in Gulpfile?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify, babeljs

I have a project that uses Babelify transforms. I have a good workflow using Watchify in my NPM run scripts:

```
package.json snippet -
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "NODE_ENV=DEV watchify -d -e js/main.js -o dist/js/main.js -v"
  },
  "main": "js/main.js",
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "babelify",
      "envify"
    ]
  }

// npm run watch
```

Now, I'm trying to move to Gulp to streamline my build cycles, but I can't seem to achieve the same bundled JS file when I programmatically trigger the watchify/browserify transforms and builds. Here's what I'm trying in my gulpfile.js:

```
function createBundle(file) {
  var bundle = watchify(browserify({
      entries: file.input,
      transform: [
        babelify,
        envify({NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV})
      ],
      debug: true,
      cache: {},
      packageCache: {},
      fullPaths: false,
      fileInfo: file
    }));

  bundle.on('update', function(e){
    if(typeof e === 'object') {
      gutil.log(gutil.colors.cyan('Changes detected on: '));
      for (var i = 0, len = e.length; i < len; i ++) {
        gutil.log(gutil.colors.magenta(e[i]));
      }
    }
    build(this);
  });

  build(bundle);
}

function build(bundle) {
  return bundle.bundle().on('error', errorHandler)
          .pipe(source(bundle._options.fileInfo.output))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('.'+bundle._options.fileInfo.destination));
}
```

I've also tried to do apply my transforms and Watchify like this in createBundle:

```
var b = browserify({
  entries: file.input,
  fileInfo: file,
  debug: true,
  cache: {},
  packageCache: {},
  plugin: [watchify],
  transform: [
    babelify,
    envify({NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV})
  ]
});
```

Why would the gulp script and running via the command-line generate different bundled files? Are there some variables that get set inherently that I'm not taking account for in my gulpfile.js?